# How to get index of list in DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

I have DataFrame like

for example

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['lists'] = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10, 100, 1000, 10000]]
df['values'] = [3, 1000]
```

3 and 1000 are 2nd elements of lists columns elements. How to get an index like that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using apply lambda;

```
df["index"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["lists"].index(x['values']),axis=1)
```

Output of df;

```
                    lists  values  index
0            [1, 2, 3, 4]       3      2
1  [10, 100, 1000, 10000]    1000      2
```